# Spotfire Calculated Column

Tags: excel, calculated-columns, spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and I hope you can help. I have a Excel sheet in excess of 280,000 rows hence my Excel sheet becomes EXTREMELY slow when I run my formula. I was hoping Spotfire could help. 
What I am trying to achieve is this: A Doctor is paid a certain amount in 2015 and then the exact same amount is taken back in 2016. I am looking to identify these paid in 2015 and taken back in 2016 transactions **only** from the 280,000 rows. The below pic shows and example of the positive and negative in Excel.
[image]

Using Columns D,L,N & J I used a SUMIFS Formula to identify in Column O The Positive and Negative transactions which offset to Zero. Can Spotfire achieve the same thing in a calculated column without the SLOWING of the Computer?

Below is what i Have so far in Spotfire not much but i am very new and the Synax is new to me. 
[image]
Can a calculated column go in after the date column and identify the Positive and Negative for 2015 and 2016 that offset to zero? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

First step [image]

Nothing came back in the 3rd column 
[image]

This is the formula i used to achieve what i needed in excel its long takes ages to process but it works. can we adopt this formula to Spotfire? 
[image]

Comment: You can copy / paste some of the data from excel into your original post as text to better help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by aggregating with an over clause. If you can paste a text version of your data set then we can make sure we get it 100% right, but here is about what you want.

Get the sum for the year 2015 for each customer. This formula states if the year of the Payment is 2015, then sum all of the Amount column and group by the CustomerID.

```
If(DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2015,Sum([Amount]) OVER ([CustomerID])) as [2015CustomerTotal]
```

Get the sum for year 2016 for each customer

```
If(DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2016,Sum([Amount]) OVER ([CustomerID])) as [2016CustomerTotal]
```

Then you can check if they zero out.

```
If([2016CustomerAmount] - [2015CustomerAmount] = 0,True,False)
```

So i got the following to work (V proud of myself)

```
If(DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2015, True,False)
```

To continue on from above I need to know that when there is a negative in 2016 and it matches a Positive in 2015 for the amount and the [Nature] and [customer id] column ids match then return me "GOT YOU" or "1" :-) any help would be greatly appreciated.

Don't know why this is not working

```
CASE WHEN ([Amount]>0) AND (DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2015) Then "GOT YA"
```

figured it out

```
CASE WHEN [Amount]>0 AND (DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2015) Then "GOT YA" else "No GOT" end
```

Ok so we are getting somewhere I feel :-) 
So the below is now telling me where there was a payment in 2015

```
CASE WHEN [Amount]>0 AND (DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2015) Then "1" else "0" end
```

and the below here is now telling me where there was a -negative amount or money taken back in 2016

```
CASE WHEN [Amount]<0 AND (DatePart("year",[Date of Payment])=2016) Then "1" else "0" end
```

Ok so i have added a visual to better describe my issue. What i would like the custom function to do is: Where there is a 1 in [Pay in 2015] and a 1 in [reimburse in 2016] and the [customer id] remains the same and the 1s from [Pay in 2015] and the 1s from [reimburse 2016] offset the [amount] column to zero then show me "1" else "0" in a new column 
[image]

Comment: Hi scsimon. thank you for taking the time to respond. I would be happy to paste a txt but I don't know how to do that :-( Also where to enter the code you have given me I dont have any drop downs for custom expressions with this Visual Type. Again sorry for being a complete beginner and Thank you

Comment: No worries @PhilipConnell. To insert a calculated column, on the tool bar in Spotfire click `Insert > Calculated Column` and just make sure you are pasting it for the correct data set.

Comment: Hi  So. I have got to inserting calculated column and the Customer ID is in red i have attached a new picture for a visual. Thank you again for you help... It was a space between customer and ID how should the code go though in the box

Comment: Put a space in it. Make CustomerID into Customer ID do it matches what your column is named

Comment: Yes. that worked but unfortunately,  nothing is coming back in the third column. I have added how I got the result in excel to the post here can the Excel formula be crafted to suit Spotfire?

Comment: Here is the link to how the excel issue was resolved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584440/find-values-in-one-column-based-on-other-columns/38618972?noredirect=1#comment64664698_38618972

Comment: @PhilipConnell  do you get data in the first two columns?

Comment: @PhilipConnell what most likely happened is the first two calculated columns you inserted didn't alias correctly. If you go to `Edit > Column Properties` and scroll to the bottom you will see these columns with long names. The names will be the entire formula. Rename them under the `General` tab to `[2016CustomerAmount]  and [2015CustomerAmount]`, respectively. Then the next formula should work for the third column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120208/discussion-between-philip-connell-and-scsimon).

Comment: @PhilipConnell sorry i was away from my system. Still having issues?

Comment: @ scsimon: No problem. Thank you for the response.  yes still having a few issue although I think I have made progress this should work CASE  
WHEN (Sum([Pay in 2015]) OVER ([Customer ID]) + Sum([Reimburse in 2016]) OVER ([Customer ID])) >=2 then 2 
ELSE 0
END
but I am getting an error stating 'invalid type for function called SUM' I will attached pic if needed

Comment: Hi this is what i need the syntax to do I nearly have it i just cant code the  "remains the same" part CASE WHEN ([Pay in 2015]=1) and ([Reimburse in 2016]=1) AND ([Customer ID] remains the same and [Nature] remains the same) then 2 else 0 end

Comment: @PhilipConnell you can't sum a non-integer or real column. That's what the error is coming from. [Pay in 2015] must be a string in your dataset.

Comment: @PhilipConnell for your "remains the same" look at NEXT() and PREVIOUS() functions. It may benefit your to use it with INTERSECT()